# What are these Xmemcached error messages?

Tags: java, tomcat, xmemcached

I'm new to Java environments (I'm a JS dev that's never had to use a large environment until now) and I got my app running on a Tomcat instance, but I'm curious as to what these messages mean. I mean, the app is functioning just fine on localhost port 8080 -- I just want to know if I should be concerned about these:

> at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>   2013-03-07 14:38:57,134 [Heal-Session-Thread] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Reconnect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail
>   2013-03-07 14:39:25,134 [Heal-Session-Thread] WARN  com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 for 15 times
>
> 2013-03-07 14:39:25,135 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Exception occured in controller
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>   2013-03-07 14:39:25,135 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR remoting: Reactor dispatch events error
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>   2013-03-07 14:39:25,135 [Heal-Session-Thread] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Reconnect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail
>   2013-03-07 14:39:55,136 [Heal-Session-Thread] WARN  com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 for 16 times
>
> 2013-03-07 14:39:55,136 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Exception occured in controller
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:39:55,136 [Heal-Session-Thread] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Reconnect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail
>
> 2013-03-07 14:39:55,136 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR remoting: Reactor dispatch events error
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:40:27,136 [Heal-Session-Thread] WARN  com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 for 17 times
>
> 2013-03-07 14:40:27,137 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Exception occured in controller
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:40:27,137 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR remoting: Reactor dispatch events error
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:40:27,137 [Heal-Session-Thread] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Reconnect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail
>
> 2013-03-07 14:41:01,138 [Heal-Session-Thread] WARN  com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 for 18 times
>
> 2013-03-07 14:41:01,138 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Exception occured in controller
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:41:01,138 [Xmemcached-Reactor-0] ERROR remoting: Reactor dispatch events error
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail,Connection refused
>       at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.impl.MemcachedConnector.onConnect(MemcachedConnector.java:406)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.dispatchEvent(Reactor.java:302)
>       at com.google.code.yanf4j.nio.impl.Reactor.run(Reactor.java:141)
>
> 2013-03-07 14:41:01,138 [Heal-Session-Thread] ERROR com.google.code.yanf4j.core.impl.AbstractController: Reconnect to 127.0.0.1:11211 fail

Answer (score 0):

It try to connect to memcached at localhost:11211.
You application is using memcached,and xmemcached is a java client.
You can startup a memcached at your machine by memcached command.

But at first, you must install memcached:
https://code.google.com/p/memcached/